# JDBC Mysql-connector in CLASSPATH, but not found

Tags: java, mysql, linux, unix, classpath

I included the lastest mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar file for a Java project in Eclipse (Added External JAR, also in Run Configuration -> Classpath).

Also, I included it in my system-wide Classpath using the export command on Linux.

But when I run my program these warnings and errors keep coming up:

```
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): RmiJdbc.RJDriver - Warning, not in CLASSPATH?

Trying to add database driver (JDBC): jdbc.idbDriver - Warning, not in CLASSPATH?

Trying to add database driver (JDBC): com.mckoi.JDBCDriver - Warning, not in CLASSPATH?

Trying to add database driver (JDBC): org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver - Warning, not in CLASSPATH?

Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:     Communications link failure
```

What do I need to do to make it work?

Comment: Check your network. It seems to be a problem in connecting the mysql server.

Comment: Pls find the correct mysql connector jar for the linux distribution... and add to Classpath.

Answer (score 1):

If your project is a Java Dynamic Web App then follow :

go to `Properties` of your project then
select `Deployment Assembly` -> `add` -> `Java Build Path Entries`  then add `mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Hy, i solved the exact same problem by adding the driver to the tomcat server lib as well

Comment: after i added the jdbc to my classpath .. and even the variables were recognised, i deployed the war file and i got the error that jdbc was not found, after trying to put them in web inf lib (still wouldn't work) I added the mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar file to my tomcat server that was running my web app and solved my problem jdbc was found